# Difference between log4j-to-slf4j and log4j-over-slf4j

Tags: logging, log4j, adapter, slf4j, bridge

I dont really get the difference between log4j-to-slf4j.jar and log4j-over-slf4j.jar. From what I read on the internet

**log4j-to-slf4j.jar:** (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html)

> "The Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter allows applications coded to the Log4j 2
>   API to be routed to SLF4J. Use of this adapter may cause some loss of
>   performance as the Log4j 2 Messages must be formatted before they can
>   be passed to SLF4J. With Log4j 2 as the implementation these would
>   normally be formatted only when they are accessed by a Filter or
>   Appender."

**log4j-over-slf4j.jar** (http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)

> "It allows log4j
>   users to migrate existing applications to SLF4J without changing a
>   single line of code but simply by replacing the log4j.jar file
>   with log4j-over-slf4j.jar, as described below. The log4j-over-slf4j
>   module contains replacements of most widely used log4j classes, namely
>   org.apache.log4j.Category, org.apache.log4j.Logger,
>   org.apache.log4j.Priority, org.apache.log4j.Level,
>   org.apache.log4j.MDC, and org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator. These
>   replacement classes redirect all work to their corresponding SLF4J
>   classes."

From what I understand both solve the same problem. But where is exactly the difference? Bridge vs Adapter?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: TLDR:  `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` is for Log4J *1.x*, while `log4j-to-slf4j.jar` is for Log4J *2.x*.

Answer (score 10):

In Log4j 2 the API is separate from the implementation.

log4j-api.jar: (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/index.html)

> The Log4j 2 API provides the interface that applications should code to and provides the adapter components required for implementers to create a logging implementation.

log4j-core.jar: (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/index.html)

> The Apache Log4j Implementation

This decoupling allows using the log4j API and an unrelated backing logging implementation, much like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) is used.

Where does log4j-to-slf4j come in? Often when dependencies using the log4j API are introduced. For instance, an application may use slf4j + a non-log4j logging implementation and then add a dependency that uses the log4j API. With log4j-to-slf4j the application's slf4j log messages and the dependencie's log4j log messages will all be routed to the same place (the logging implementation).

Meanwhile, log4j 1 doesn't have the API/implementation separation. The previously outlined scenario may still arise. In that situation log4j-over-slf4j can be used as a drop in replacement for log4j.jar (i.e. log4j 1).

> **How does it work?**
>
> The log4j-over-slf4j module contains replacements of most widely used log4j classes...To use log4j-over-slf4j in your own application, the first step is to locate and then to replace log4j.jar with log4j-over-slf4j.jar
>
> In most situations, replacing a jar file is all it takes in order to migrate from log4j to SLF4J.

-- http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

In summary, they accomplish the same thing but do so very differently and are used for different log4j versions (1 vs 2).

Answer (score 4):

Please correct me if I am wrong - will try to answer my question.

I just had a look on mvnrepository.org - there is no log4j-to-slf4j.jar beneath version 2.x and from the link I pasted above it is stated that this is an Adapter of log4j-**2.x** and not 1.x. Also its provided by the Apache Foundation.

In contrary the log4j-over-slf4j.jar is documented on slf4j.org and does redirect log4j-**1.x** records to the slf4j-api.

So I think that I mixed apples and pears.

Comment: I think you got it. The biggest difference is that log4j has two versions.  `log4j-over-slf4j` helps migrating legacy code to a new logging framework by taking care of sending messages to slf4j (which then forwards it further to whatever framework you are using for logging). `log4j-to-slf4j` kind of does the same, but is not specifically made for legacy project migrating (still can be used for that, I guess)

Don't forget: If there's a 'logging' within the GAV identifier, log4j2.X is meant. Made it easier for me to distinguish

Answer (score 2):

[log4j-to-slf4j.jar](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html):
The Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter allows applications coded to the **Log4j 2 API** to be routed to SLF4J.

[log4j-over-slf4j.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j) ：
It allows **log4j users** to migrate existing applications to SLF4J without changing a single line of code but simply by replacing the log4j.jar file with log4j-over-slf4j.jar